# Scala - Function apply vs match clause

Tags: scala

This Scala code a) works well:

```
val f : Function[String, String] = { case "a" => "b"}
f.apply("a") //returns "b"
```

And is the same than b)

```
"a" match { case "a" => "b" } //returns "b"
```

1) Is match clause in b) syntactic sugar for a)?

2) Why does this not work...?

```
{ case "a" => "b"}.apply("b") //Does not compile
```

Thanks!

Comment: `apply()` is a [method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) of the `Function` class. The code `case "a" => "b"` is not an instance of a class that has an `apply()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers:

1. No. a) is a pattern-matching anonymous function (section 8.5 of the Scala language spec), while b) is a pattern-maching expression (section 8.4 of the Scala language spec). They are subtly different.
2. This does not work because it requires a type to parse as a function. You can make it work with a type annotation:

   `({ case "a" => "b"}: PartialFunction[String, String]).apply("b")`